# Kubernetes Fission setup fails

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-fission

I am trying to install Fission on a Kubernetes Cluster. When I ran:

```
helm install --namespace fission https://github.com/fission/fission/releases/download/0.4.1/fission-all-0.4.1.tgz
```

I gave some errors:

```
E0218 09:14:41.578967    3357 portforward.go:331] an error occurred forwarding 36281 -> 44134: error forwarding port 44134 to pod b29ecdfb514ada5583e99e416d3fc07e25d5bcf71206b450a1f4f972a9d2502b, uid : exit status 1: 2018/02/18 09:14:41 socat[26057] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:44134, 16): Connection refused
Error: transport is closing
```

How can I fix these errors and install Fission?

My Cluster OS is `Debian 9` and Kubernetes version is:

```
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.3", GitCommit:"", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-02-07T11:55:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**Update:**

I solved the previous error and i could install Fission. but i have a new error. When i ran `fission env create --name nodejs --image fission/node-env:0.4.1`

i gave this error:

```
Failed to create environment: Post 
http://178.162.203.65:31313/v2/environments: dial tcp 178.162.203.65:31313: 
getsockopt: connection refused
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I own found the answer of the question. When I was installing the Kubernetes. Exactly After ran `kubeadm init` I must ran :

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Neither `root` nor `none-root` must ran the above command.(I don't know why)